# ID Card printers and software

Tags: printer

My company of about 60 people currently uses a Magicard Pronto ID Card printer and the Magicard ID card software. The printer would be OK (not great) if they released 64 bit drivers for it, but Magicard ID is without a doubt one of the worst pieces of software I have ever used, ever. It would be OK for occasional hiring, but my company is looking to add a lot of people rather quickly.

Does anybody know of decent ID-card printing software, and possibly a replacement printer? I might just "accidentally" run over this one with my truck a few times.

Comment: Please post vid if any running over occurs.

Comment: I think you answered your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Asure ID card software.  There is a trial version that you can check out at http://www.safecardid.com/blog/asure-id-2009-software-download-trial/.  Make sure that you are in admin mode on your computer and you use Internet Explorer for the download.

If you want recommendations about a printer, Safe-Card ID can provide options for you to look at as well.

Hope you like the Asure.  I know a number of people happy with that product.

Answer (score 0):

As sort-of a side answer, I contacted Magicard technical support, and they say 64 bit drivers for their printers are due out next month. We'll see if that's true.